# How can I create a new formula that removes all the coefficients that have NA in the summary?

Tags: r

When I use simple lm function. I have NA for some coefficients.
How can I create a new formula that removes all the coefficients that have NA in the summary?

**Example**:

```
iris[which(iris$Species=="setosa"),]$Petal.Width<-1
iris$SomeFactor<-round(log(rgeom(n = nrow(iris),prob = 0.1)+1))
model<-list()
for(i in unique(iris$Species)){
  data<-iris[which(iris$Species==i),]
  model[[i]]<-lm(formula = formula("Sepal.Length~Sepal.Width + 
                                    Petal.Length + as.factor(SomeFactor)+ 
                                    Petal.Width"),data = data)
}
model[["setosa"]]

Call:
  lm(formula = formula("Sepal.Length~Sepal.Width + Petal.Length + Petal.Width"), 
     data = data)

Coefficients:
  (Intercept)   Sepal.Width  Petal.Length   Petal.Width  
2.3037        0.6674        0.2834            NA
```

And I want that for the group setosa the formula will be without Petal.Width.

just: `Sepal.Length~Sepal.Width + Petal.Length + SomeFactor2+ SomeFactor3`.

Usually, I use step function. and then take the formula from the model.
but it takes a lot of time. and reduce a lot of coefficients.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `drop.terms` to, guess, drop the problem term. You will need to be carefull with the intercept term, it's in the formula by default. That's why I subtract 1 from `which` below.

```
model<-list()
for(i in unique(iris$Species)){
  data<-iris[which(iris$Species==i),]
  model[[i]] <- lm(formula = formula("Sepal.Length~Sepal.Width + Petal.Length + Petal.Width"),data = data)
  if(any(is.na(coef(model[[i]])))){
    cf <- coef(model[[i]])
    fmla <- drop.terms(terms(model[[i]]), which(is.na(cf)) - 1, keep.response = TRUE)
    model[[i]] <- lm(fmla, data = data)
  }
}

model[["setosa"]]
```

Comment: This works great. But there is a little problem: if there is a coefficient that there is NA for him but in the formula, it comes after specific factor, drop.terms will not remove him.

Comment: @AnnaBokovskaya Can you give an example as an edit to your question? If so, please put it last, so that I can immediately see it.

Comment: Hey I edited the answer, with the little problem that arose if you add factors.

Comment: @AnnaBokovskaya It gave me errors but when I changed the name of the df from `data` to `dat` it all went well. This is probably because `data` already is a `base R` function, and it seems there was a names conflict. Try it and then say something.

Comment: when I change it to different name it still doesn't remove the NA coefficients. `which(is.na(cf))` give the wrong number because `as.factor(SomeFactor)` split to several factors.

Answer (score 1):

You get the NA as coefficient since there is no variability in petal width for the subset of iris you are studying.
If you want a separate model, I would just create a subset of the data and use lm on that subset. I wouldn't do it in the iteration you made. You could also use stepwise regression methods and then the petal width will be left out for the 'setosa' subspecies since it has no variability on that variable.